# passing sqlplus output to a csh variable

Tags: sqlplus, csh

What is the correct csh syntax to store the output of a sqlPlus block?

```
sqlplus -s / <<SQL
set feedback off
set linesize 100
set lines 150
set pages 0
set head off
set serveroutput on size 10000

select 1 from dual;
SQL
```

In this example, I'd like to be able to assign the value '1' to a variable in the csh script. Using another shell variant is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the variables in SQL*Plus into a file that you can then source once control has returned to your CSH program.

Note that I'm also showing you how to store the output of a SQL*Plus column value in a SQL*Plus variable using the `column` statement. You can skip this step if your code is simple, but I though this was a worthwhile addition.

```
sqlplus -s apps/apps@VIS <<SQL
set feedback off
set linesize 100
set lines 150
set pages 0
set head off
set serveroutput on size 10000
column result new_value result

select 1 as result from dual;

prompt Variable result = &result.

spool output.csh
prompt set result = &result.
spool off
SQL

source output.csh
echo "Back in CSH and result = $result "
```